How to symbolize code for ladder operators
As suggested in  this answer, I am considering symbolizing the function "NonCommutativeMultiplyNew" from the following code:
ScalarQ[n_?NumberQ] := True
ScalarQ[_aOp] := False
ScalarQ[_aOpDagger] := False
SetScalar[k_] := (ScalarQ[k] = True);

(*Define transformations required to canonicalize operator \
expressions*)

NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[] := 1
NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa_] := aa
NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa___, xx_ + yy_, bb___] := 
 NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa, xx, bb] + 
  NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa, yy, bb]
NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa___, NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[bb_, cc__],
   dd___] := NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa, bb, cc, dd]
NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa___, i_?ScalarQ, bb___] := 
 i*NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa, bb]
NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa___, i_?ScalarQ*cc_, bb___] := 
 i*NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa, cc, bb]
NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa___, aOp[i_Integer], aOp[j_Integer], 
   bb___] /; j < i := NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa, aOp[j], aOp[i], bb]
NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa___, aOpDagger[i_Integer], 
   aOpDagger[j_Integer], bb___] /; j < i := 
 NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa, aOpDagger[j], aOpDagger[i], bb]
NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa___, aOp[i_Integer], aOpDagger[j_Integer],
    bb___] /; j =!= i := 
 NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa, aOpDagger[j], aOp[i], bb]
NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa___, 
 aOp[\[AliasDelimiter]i_Integer], aOpDagger[i_], 
     bb___] := -NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aa, aOpDagger[i], aOp[i], 
      bb]

which would simplify and reorder code like:
SetScalar[c];
SetScalar[k];
NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aOp[4], 
 NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[k*aOp[1], aOp[2], aOpDagger[1]] + 
  c*NonCommutativeMultiplyNew[aOp[2], aOp[1], aOp[3]]]

I'd like it so that I can write something like:
$$ka_2 + ka_1^\dagger a_1 a_2+ c*a_1**a_2**a_3$$
or maybe
$$ka_2 + ka_1^\dagger a_1  \otimes  a_2+ c*a_1 \otimes a_2 \otimes a_3$$
Is there a way that this can be done in a straightforward way? It would be nice if it could be made like the NCalgebra package just a single symbol does the work for you.

Why not just use NonCommutativeMultiply instead of defining a new one? You can do Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply] to allow changes to its definitions. (This doesn't answer your question of course.)
